# Error en Docker para Mac M1

Tags: docker, arm

Al instalar docker en una maquina virtual en un equipo con un procesador M1, vota el siguiente error, alguien a podido solucionar este error? encontre que es por no activar Hyper-Virtualization en la maquina virtual pero esto no se puede ya que no es un procesador x86. Quisiera saber si algún desarollador a encontrado alguna solución el error?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cómo hiciste para instalarlo? Seguiste las instrucciones de la documentación? https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/install/

Comment: Si, realice todos los pasos de manera adecuada pero la documentación que me compartes es para instalarlo en Mac OS de manera nativa, yo lo estoy instalando dentro de una maquina virtual con windows. Es decir de manera virtualizada. Así que seguí las instrucciones para instalarlo en windows. Es de esa manera que encontré este error.